# Python Read selected Excel columns into arrays

Tags: excel, python-2.7

I have an excel spreadsheet that I need to read the values into arrays as follows

A[0] to A[24] needs to have the values of E4 to E28

B[0] to B[24] needs to have the values of H4 to H28

C[0] to C[24] needs to have the values of K4 to K28

and so on where I am reading every 3rd column for a total of 7 columns.

How would I do this in Python 2.7? Any suggestions or help would be great.
I have worked out how to read a single cell into a variable, but need to make this a less manual process than have to manually read and assign 175 cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`openpyxl`](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl). A simple example follows.

If you have this excel document, say `Workbook1.xlsx`:

[image]

```
import openpyxl as px

W = px.load_workbook('Workbook1.xlsx', use_iterators = True)
p = W.get_sheet_by_name(name = 'Sheet1')

print p['A1'].value
print [ p['A%s'%i].value for i in range(1,10) ]
```

will print:

```
1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you @Sait ! I receive the following error TypeError: 'IterableWorksheet' object has no attribute 'getitem'

Comment: Anyone with a solution to this please?

Comment: @user3754712 What versions do you use? This example works on Mac OS with openpyxl (2.2.5) and Python 2.7.

Comment: thanks, I updated the version of openpyxl I have and it has solved the problem.